# C programming- read from text file

Tags: c, text

it's about reading from a text file.

I have 3 command line arguments:

1. name of text file
2. delay time
3. how many line(s) want to read.

I want to read that text file by user specified line numbers till text file ends.

For example, the first time I read 5 lines and then the program asks `how many line(s) do you want to read?`. I would enter `7` it reads lines 5 to 12.

This would repeat until the end of the file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <string.h>
void delay(unsigned int mseconds)
{
clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
while (goal > clock());
}
int countlines(const char *filename) {
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
int ch, last = '\n';
int lines = 0;

if (fp != NULL) {
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;
        last = ch;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if (last != '\n')
        lines++;
}
return lines;
}
int main(int argc, char *arg[])
{
FILE *ptDosya;
char ch;
ch = arg[1][0];
int s2;
int satir = 0;
int spaceCounter=0;
int lineCount, x = 0;
lineCount = atoi(arg[3]);
s2 = atoi(arg[2]);
printf("dosya %d satir icerir.\n", countlines(arg[1]));
ptDosya = fopen(arg[1], "r");
if (ptDosya != NULL)
{
    while (ch != EOF&& x < lineCount)
    {
        ch = getc(ptDosya);
        printf("%c", ch);
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            delay(s2);
            x++;
        }
    }
    while (x < countlines(arg[1]))
    {
        printf("satir sayisi giriniz:");
        scanf("%d", &lineCount);
         // i don't know what should i do in this loop..
    x=x+lineCount;
    }
} 

else {
    printf("dosya bulunamadi");
}
printf("\n\nend of file!\n");
fclose(ptDosya);
return 0;
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: can you tell us what is your problem with this code? (I see one: your delay loop is a CPU intensive loop, not very good!)

Comment: it needs some addition. this code takes the lines number once it doesn's asks till text ends.

Answer (score 1):

Your `delay` function uses a busy loop.  This is unnecessarily expensive in terms of computing power.  It would be very unwelcome to do this on a battery operated device.  Furthermore, `clock()` does not necessarily return a number of milliseconds.  The unit used by the `clock()` function can be determined using the `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` macro.  Unfortunately, there is no portable way to specify a delay expressed in milliseconds, POSIX conformant systems have `usleep()` and `nanosleep()`.

Your line counting function is incorrect: you count 1 line too many, unless the file ends without a trailing linefeed.

Here is an improved version:

```
int countlines(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    int ch, last = '\n';
    int lines = 0;

    if (fp != NULL) {
        while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if (ch == '\n')
                lines++;
            last = ch;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        if (last != '\n')
            lines++;
    }
    return lines;
}
```

There are issues in the `main()` function too:

- You so not verify that enough arguments are passed on the command line.
- You do not check for `EOF` in the main reading loop.
- You do not repeat the process in a loop until end of file, nor do you even ask the question `how many line(s) do you want to read?` after reading the specified number of lines...

Comment: Yeah you are right but i'm not good at c and its libraries. And i cant do that how i index last written line and keep going from there

Comment: @f.koglu: sorry, I do not understand your comment.

Comment: For example program i run the program and program write 5 lines. And then ask me how many lines to read i write 8. How can i start with sixth line?? I have to put a loop? Can you write this loop?

Comment: @f.koglu: after you have read the 5 lines, ask the user for input with `printf()` and `scanf()`, then keep reading the number of lines entered... and put this in a loop to repeat until you reach the end of the file.  I cannot write the full assignment myself, it is for you to figure.

Comment: Yes i know this algorithmic type but i cant put this in in code

Comment: And i cant understand this point, first i take number of line from command line. When i want to take this again should i assign the value another veriable?

Comment: It does not matter which variable you use for the rest of the program.  You are not going to execute the beginning of `main()` again.  You can use `lineCount` first as `lineCount = atoi(arg[3]);` to read the number of lines specified on the command line, and then with `scanf("%d", &lineCount);` to get the next count from the user.  `lineCount` is a local variable, you can use for multiple purposes, but combining these into a single loop is tricky, use 2 separate loops.

Comment: OK thanks i will try it  if i have some troubles can i ask you?

Answer (score 0):

First, if the file cannot be found, the countlines method returns zero. You should use that value to write the error message, and skip the rest of the code.

Second, in the next loop, you use

```
    if (ch != '\n') {
        printf("%c", ch);
    } else {
        printf("\n");
        delay(s2);
        x++;
    }
```

Why the two printf statements? They will print the same thing.
Perhaps something like this:

```
 ch = getc(ptDosya);
 /* exit the loop here if you hit EOF */

 printf("%c", ch);  /* Why not putc() or putchar()  ? */
 if (ch == '\n') {
    x++;
    if ( x == lineCount ) {
       x = 0;
       lineCount = requestNumberOfLinesToRead();
    } else {
      sleep(s2); /* instead of delay(). Remember to #include unistd.h */
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you understand my problem? Can you write missing part of my code?